# Feynman's Paradox concerning Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, charge

A paradox or rather a dilemma, as you might like to call it, from the portion of *electromagnetism*:

> A *charged particle* with charge $q$ is moving with a *uniform velocity* $v$. So it has an **electric** and a **magnetic field** associated with it. Now if I, the observer, *start running parallel* to the charge with *uniform velocity* $v$, then, the charged particle appears to be *static* from my reference frame and hence I see that its associated magnetic field has, all on a sudden, **vanished**. But a *stationary observer* still finds that the charged particle has an **associated magnetic field**.

How can I explain this paradox? Is it anyhow related to "*electromagnetism not being invariant under Galilean transformation*"?

Comment: I think that the term _Feynman's Paradox_ doesn't concern your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a paradox, if you study lorentz transformation, you see that Electric and magnetic fields are as linked to each other as space is to time, you can sometimes find a reference frame where the magnetic field is zero.
see the transformation here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity#The_E_and_B_fields